# Manage local machines using GPO and Azure AD Domain Services

Tags: entra-domain-services

I would like to get rid of my on-prem DC but still want to apply GPO to my local computers.
I have followed the tutorial on managing GPO using Azure AD Domain Services and created a test lab using testlab.onmicrosoft.com as my Azure AD Tenant as well as my Azure AD DS domain. I have also created a management VM and joined that to the domain. There is a default AADDC Computers OUs created on the Management Server.
*Is there a way to join my local machines to the domain so they will show up in the AADDC Computers OU and I can apply GPO to them?*

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can configure the Vnet where Azure AD Domain Servicers (AAD DS) is running with a VPN Gateway, and use that to either create a Point to Site VPN connect on the local machines, or a Site to Site VPN connection for the entire local network, which will allow you to join anything on your network to AAD DS.

Beware though, this is not a recommended approach and is actually a bad use case of AAD DS since it is not meant to be a replacement for a normal Active Directory Domain Services (Ad DS), there's a lot of limitations you need to be aware of.

I highly suggest you read the following links:

- **Common use-cases and scenarios for Azure Active Directory Domain Services:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/scenarios
- **Compare self-managed Active Directory Domain Services, Azure Active Directory, and managed Azure Active Directory Domain Services:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/compare-identity-solutions
- **Tutorial: Create and manage a VPN gateway using Azure portal:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-create-gateway-portal